NET Core - gRPC Server
What NuGet package should I install to enable gRPC server functionality in the latest version of a .NET Core console application ?
I tried installing GRPC nuget ,but cannot do this - message "cannot be mapped".What nuget should be installed ?
Thanks!
RE: Solution : Installed Grpc.Core and it worked correctly
